Automator script error -212
Im on an intel macOS Catalina and I am trying to create a automation using apple script to run a command in zsh terminal. The command is to set new defaults for my bash profile and it works perfectly when isolated, but if I put it in the automator script and make the shortcut visible at the dock, it throws an error.
The error says:
"The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error: "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.Automator error -212.)"
and my script is
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "source ~/.zprofile"
        do script "clear"
    end tell
end run

There is no solution posted on the internet AFAIK.

Have you tried running that script directly from Script Editor?  (That's probably the best way to debug (and to write!) AppleScript.)
I did, and it stops on the first line with a (different) error message.
But after removing the {input, parameters}, it runs fine.  (I'm guessing that the documentation you got that from was indicating that you could use either input or parameters — though in fact it's taken as an identifier, so any single word will do.  Since it's optional, the simplest thing is to omit it entirely.)
So that seems to be the immediate problem.
However, that's not the only problem with the script.  The activate command brings the Terminal app to the front, along with any windows it has already open.  But each do script opens a new window with a new shell, and runs the command there — it does not affect any windows which were already open (which I guess is your intent).
To do that, you need to tell it to use an existing window.  The simplest way seems to be do script "……" in window 0, which uses the current tab in the frontmost window.
(There are other variations which would let you select other tabs and windows.  See the Terminal documentation for more; the simplest way is to run ‘File → Open Dictionary…’ from the Script Editor, and choose ‘Terminal.app’ from the resulting dialog.)
(Note: this was tested on macOS 12 Monterey, but I expect it'll apply to some earlier and later versions too.)
